# Should I have 2 activities, one for viewing text and one for editing, or vice-versa?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got a part in my app where the user can view some notes (text) or edit notes.  I was thinking of making a view with both EditText and TextViews, then depending on what they want to do, show the appropriate views.  The possibility is there to switch views in the same activity.

Anyone have any thoughts or insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off of Binyamin's answer, remember the documentation states,

> An Activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do.

Thus, it makes sense to split separate actions (such as the two you described) into separate `Activity`s. Organizing your `Activity`s as separate entities in this manner will give your application a simple and easy-to-understand logical workflow. It will also make your application more modular and easy to work with in the future.

Comment: I think I like this better because things may change and remembering which view goes with which 'mode' could get messy.

Answer (score 1):

I would separate them into two activities:

1. If you have two different activities to do, put them in two different `Activities`.
2. This way you don't mix the logic, and implementation of them.
3. You avoid future conflicts if those tasks are to be more complicated.